# Invalidation of Fragments managed by FragmentStateAdapter of ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

My setup is as follows:

- `ViewPager2` instance uses ...
- `FragmentStateAdapter` as the adapter.
- `getSupportFragmentManager` was passed to constructor of `FragmentStateAdapter`.

**The task**

In some situations I would like the Fragments to be recreated "from scratch" rather then from their `savedInstanceState`. In other words, I would like to tell the `ViewPager2`/`FragmentStateAdapter`/`FragmentManger` not to pass `savedInstanceState` bundle down to `Fragment.onCreate(Bundle)`.

**Question**

Is there some way to 'invalidate' cache or whatever of `ViewPager2`/`FragmentStateAdapter`/`FragmentManager` so I could control when the Fragment should be 'invalidated' (when the Fragment should be created "from scratch" rather then from its `savedInstanceState`)?

**Possible solution (insufficient for my needs)**

I know that there are `FragmentStateAdapter.getItemId(int)` and `FragmentStateAdapter.containsItem(long)` which can be used to control instantiation of Fragments. However, this solution requires a proper management of (in my case hundreds of) IDs and somehow update/modify them each time the Fragments should be recreated.

Isn't there really a way to invalidate some kind of global cache?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: I didn't find a simple `invalidate cache` solution. I ended up with a workaround: data are stored in my custom  `Application` instance, then I reference them from `Fragment` by their `UUID`. Then, each time the fragment is recreated I evaluate if the data with given `UUID` exist and whether the data is up-to-date. If no, I update the UI of the `Fragment` accordingly. So the only thing which gets persisted by the fragment is the `UUID:String`. This workaround is sufficient for my needs. Hopefully will help you too.